# "SOLVED" Set of problems after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

Previous System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Now Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS in settings icon under about ---- in TimeShift program shows Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.)

- **Memory**: 62. GIB
- **Processor**: Intel Xeon® CPU E3-1240 v5 @3.50 Hz 8
- **Graphics**: livmpipe (LLVM 8.0 256 bits)
- **GNOME**: 3.82.2
- **OS type**: 64-bit
- **Disk**: 982.8

Disks installed:

- 1.0 TB Disk – Samsung SSD 97- Pro 1TB (where OS resides)
- 4.0 TB Hard Disk WDC WD4005FZBX-00K5WB0 (01.01A01) Labeled Backup. Used to backup documents from Ubuntu 18 & Windows XP. Mounted at run/timeshift/backup
- 4.0 TB Hard Disk WDC WD4002FYYZ-01B7CB1 (01.01M03) Labeled Backup1. Used to backup    ubuntu 18 before upgrade.   Not mounted
- 999 GB Block Device 999 GB — 837 GB free (16.2% full) /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
- 1.0 GB Block Device .0 GB (1,023,410,176 bytes) /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1

Upgraded Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04.28 on October 28, 2020.

### Problems

1. Moving the program from one display screen to 2nd display screen will remain logged in but see a brief flash of login screen or in some cases the program will exit back to login screen.

Downloaded Ubuntu 20 from Ubuntu website to hard disk and installed from hard disk.  When downloading Ubuntu 20 and installing did not observe any errors but walked away for away while it was installing.   Do not "appear" to have problems with package manager.  Is there a way to check it for sure?

PROBLEMS SOLVED:

```
1. Main problem the settings icon on the side menu --- when you double click in to open – screen goes to main log in screen.  
2. LibreOffice when doing a save will go back to main log in screen.  Seems to be no pattern sometimes it saves but 95 % time does not since upgrade to Ubuntu 20.  Have upgraded LibreOffice to 7.0.3.1.  Did not eliminated the problem.
3. After upgrade in LibreOffice the problem of going back to main log in screen is happening on pdf opened and saved from the internet.
4. Sound will work sometimes or will show a dummy icon for sound.  If you open the terminal and imput the following in the sound returns:  pulseaudio --kill; sleep 2s; sudo alsa force-reload ; pulseaudio –start     kill; sleep 2s; sudo alsa force-reload ; pulseaudio –start
5. kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
6. [sudo] password for rob: 
7. Sorry, try again.
8. [sudo] password for rob: 
9. Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
10. Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer.
11. E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Too many arguments.
12. 
13. I believe this is part of a bug referred to here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1875252.
14. Terminal screen readout: Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
15. Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
16. Tried to play a mp4 video went to log in screen.  Other mp4 videos have played.
17. Backup Failed:  Error creating directory /mnt/4d811811-c910-4652-b45e-968d5a5ffe3f/Backup: Permission denied.  Changed disks permissions.
18. When printing it shows in the box:print to file
19. HP Laser Jet M505 – this one prints.
20. HP Laser Jet M505 – this one does not print
21. Both displays flickering – changed to recommended drivers.
```

HERE IS WHAT I DONE SO FAR:

When I upgraded LibreOffice on about November 1.   I opened up Software & Updates Manager:
Checked all repositories except Source code are enabled;
Switched to fastest download server.
Enabled Canonical Partners repository.
Update tab – sign up for all updates types – already enabled.
Enabled livepatch – Not enabled.
No  drivers to update.
Installed Synaptic package manager.
Installed codecs, MS fonts, flash and other useful packages.
Installed flash player.
Decrease Swap use   vm.swappiness = 10.
Setup firewall installed gufw package.  Enable firewall.
Did complete update of system from terminal.  Since then it has updated via livepatch at least once.
Then used “Timeshift” program to revert back to Ubuntu 18 but system says it still at Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.  Timeshift program states Ubuntu 18.
Then update everything including the snaps via terminal.

Update program did an update today (11/20/2020)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We cannot address all eight problems in the AskUbuntu format, which is one question / multiple answers, so please spread out common issues among several more questions. AskUbuntu is ill-suited for conversational or complex threads - your question works best when there is a single, clear, answerable question. Do not report reproducible crashes and other bugs here -- this is not the bug tracker. Make sure to include all relevant data in your question if you want useful, effective answers.

Comment: The problems may indeed be related. Perhaps the upgrade did not complete fully. How did you carry out the upgrade? Were there any errors? Are you having any package management issues? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Downloaded Ubuntu 20 from Ubuntu website to hard disk and installed from hard disk. When downloading Ubuntu 20 and installing did not observe any errors but walked away for away while it was installing. Do not "appear" to have problems with package manager. Is there a way to check it for sure?  Would it be considered a package management issue if the Ubuntu Software center will not do updates.?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put SOLVED in the title and the solution in the question. This is a question answer site. Please use the button below to answer your own question and put the solution in the answer. Then after the wait period accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will mark the problem as solved and help others.